# How do I install my own package-candidate with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've just created a new cabal package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-python-0.1.0.0/candidate). I'd like to test it on a separate computer before publishing. Running `cabal install json-python` fails to find the candidate, which makes sense. Is there a way to tell cabal to target candidates, or a specific url of the tarball? Otherwise, is the best way to install the package to `wget` the tarball url from my other computer, run `tar xf`, and then cabal install from the local package? It would be great if someone could add some of this information to the otherwise nice introduction at http://hackage.haskell.org/upload.

Comment: You can save a couple steps by passing the tarball url to cabal, e.g. `cabal install http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-python-0.1.0.0/candidate/json-python-0.1.0.0.tar.gz`. However, I too would like to know if there was a way to make candidates (or selected candidates) part of your "default" cabal index.

Answer (score 1):

These days you can use cabal.project and specify a [remote tarball](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-packages), e.g.

```
packages:
  .
  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-python-0.1.0.0/candidate/json-python-0.1.0.0.tar.gz
```